# Character Encoding in iframes

Tags: http, browser, character-encoding

I have a text file encoded in ISO-8859-1.  If you [view it in Google Chrome](http://nickretallack.com/experiments/encoding/iframed/content.txt), it displays correctly.  However, if you [iframe it](http://nickretallack.com/experiments/encoding/iframed/), it looks wrong.  Also, it always looks wrong in Firefox.

I have noticed this same behavior with various different servers and browsers.  However, if I use Google Chrome and run the server and browser on the same machine, the iframe's content displays correctly.

What should I do to make the file show up correctly in all situations?  It seems like the browser should be able to figure it out, but in many situations it fails to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You’re serving the file with `Content-Type: text/plain`, which amounts to asking the browser to guess. Evidently, not every situation results in the same guess.

Set it to `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1`.

Comment: Is there any easy way to get my server to set that information automatically when it serves the file?  I mean, I'm running linux, and libmagic seems to know what the encoding is.

Comment: Technically, by RFC 2046, the default charset for text/plain is US-ASCII, but browsers, when encountering bytes outside ASCII range, seem to make their guesses. Specifying charset in HTTP headers indeed seems to be the only way to deal with the situation.

Comment: I'm specifying the charset now in my test environment, but it still isn't rendering correctly in the iframe in any browser.

Comment: Alright, wrote a simple app in nodejs to test this and it works.