# iFrame does not display accented characters correctly

Tags: html, iframe, utf-8

I have an HTML page:

```html
<html>
 <head>
  Web page
 </head>
 <body>
  <p>This sentence has multibyte characters:腶 摿斠榱 耜僇鄗 輑鄟銆 趀跅, 吪吙 櫱瀯灂 猺矠筸 禖 箄 鸄齴, 蒛 齞齝囃 鼏噳墺 跠跬 劁 墐墆墏 甀瞂硾 噦噞, 蛶觢豥 箄縴儳 勯噚嶢 鷜鷙 毹, 綧 忣抏旲 痑祣筇 踆跾
        </p>
     <p>á, é, í, ó, ú, ü, ñ, ¿, ¡</p>
 </body>
</html>
```

When on its own, this page displays correctly.  However, I have a site that is trying to display this page inside an iFrame.  There, the accented characters appear as black diamonds with question marks.  I have tried adding in the meta tag specifying UTF-8 encoding (which the file is saved as ), but this does not fix the page with the iFrame.  In fact, when you add that tag to the HTML page, it breaks that page on its own as well.  What am I missing here?

Comment: what browser are you testing in?

Comment: And where did you add the meta tag

Comment: Yes, show the meta tag.  Also, you can not have "Web page" in the `<head>`, it needs to be `<head><title>Web Page</title></head>`.  If SO doesn't allow it, just don't put that in there or drop it into the `<body>`

Comment: I tested in Chrome.  I tried placing the meta tag on my overall page containing the iframe and in the web page that goes within the iframe.  Neither worked.  I found the answer specified below - embarrassingly obvious, but got overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the fun was that the file was ANSI encoding, not UTF-8.  The page worked on its own because the browser auto-detected ANSI and showed it thus.  However, I have UTF-8 forced on the page containing the iFrame, so it tried to show an ANSI format file in UTF-8 - hence the problem.  The answer is to properly encode the web page in UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

if you have control of the server where the iframe file is being served from, you may want to change content type on server side:
[Character Encoding in iframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12827528/character-encoding-in-iframes)